# Disable Chrome clipboard popups WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, popup, webdriver-io

I'm trying to disable the chrome clipboard popup/notification using webdriverIO (Selenium) for automation. I tried setting chrome options but still it doesn't disable it. I want to click a web element that is behind this popup, so I don't want this popup to appear in automation. I tried disabling the clipboard settings manually but selenium opens a new session every time which refreshes the settings. Also, it is not possible to inspect using developer tools. It is not an alert so accepting/dismissing alert does not work either.

```
browser.alertAccept();
```

or

```
browser.alertDismiss();
```

[image: Chrome Clipboard popup]

```
chromeOptions: {
    args: [
        'disable-infobars',
        'disable-popup-blocking',
        'disable-notifications'
    ],
    prefs: {
        'profile.default_content_settings.popups' : 2,
        'profile.default_content_settings.notifications' : 2,
    }
}
```

Please help me with this issue, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround might be to switch to the popup and dismiss it.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().dismiss();
```

EDIT: I found an interesting Website. Try the code at the end of this site: http://blog.amolchavan.space/block-push-notification-on-chrome-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The website is also interesting but it did not get clear understanding of the solution. I tried with alert accept and dismiss.


browser.alertAccept();

But webdriverIO doesn't recognize it as an alert. I think it is something related to setting chrome preferences for clipbaord.

Comment: `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("disable-notifications");
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` Nonetheless this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I see many people also suggest to use `profile.default_content_settings` so it may be depend on chrome version. Current chrome version will work with this code as follows

```
chromeOptions: {
    prefs: {
        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 2,
        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 2,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, this worked for me with version 103 of Chrome (Jul 2022):

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard": {
    '*': {'setting': 1}
}}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

...

currentDriver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=SELENIUM_URL, options=chrome_options)
with currentDriver as driver:
    ...
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.